# Split html to show CrystalQuartz graph separately

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I built a project (ASP.Net Core) to show in an animated graph the timing of some data extractors I have, where each data extractor has a CronExpression to define that timing for running it.

The framework I'm using to build/show that graph is [**CrystalQuartz**](https://github.com/guryanovev/CrystalQuartz), where I just need (can) is to create the jobs and triggers that will run, add them to the scheduler and call the controller */quartz*. What happens beyond the point of calling */quartz* (loading pages, scripts and css) is not on my control, and there starts my "*issue*".

I want to load the graph in just part of the HTML (like the bottom half), where on the top half I would put some links/buttons to change/reload the jobs that are running on the graph without reloading the whole page.
The challenge here is that, anyway I try to call/load the result of calling */quartz*, it loads the graph on the whole page.

**The question:** Is there a way of really splitting the html in two (not using PartialView, doesn't work) where I control the content of *html B* by the same controller I control *html A*?

Comment: how about .net core view components https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I got the idea, but in that case I'll need to call */quartz* controller from InvokeAsync method (inside my model), because I don't have name of view or something like that. Some way of "breaking the rules" and calling a controller from the model?

Comment: would something like this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078875/refresh-view-component-net-core-rc2

Comment: Didn't work as I want because the return from *quartz* controller is not a partial view, and it also got stuck processing it on the whole page with the message on console "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://localhost:5001/?path=application.css"."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

The way for having other html inside my html is using iframe.
To load the result of a controller inside that iframe, just need to set the attribute **src="*[route]*"** (in my case **src="/quartz"**).

Because of the fact the data used on the graph is all loaded on backend, I only needed to call the controller that reload that data and them reload the iframe (***[iframe]*.src = *[iframe]*.src**).